# Are exceptions from webpages always "just" timeouts and http error pages?

Tags: java, asp.net

I'm currently trying to understand how java.net.URLConnection and web pages interact. If I take it that the web page is as currently often done via ASP.Net then exceptions are possible to occur and if an exception occurs instead of the expected web page an error web page is displayed (or it runs and runs and runs depending on the exact problem).

Now I know that the method getContent() can throw errors if it has troubles getting the content. But what happens in the case of an unhandled exception on the asp.net page. Is that then such a case of an IOException? Or what do I get back there (a timeout? Or the content of the error page?)?

**Clarification:**
It is clear to me how it is seen from the ASP.Net side. Thus an unhandled error => yellow page of death. My question is tehre in relation to java. What does java get in those cases (the getContent()).

---

As Info: I'm not creating the java program, but instead need to understand how it works so that a few modifications I'm doing on the side of the ASP.Net program cause no different handling than before, thus I can't really test things out there (as I have no control over the java program itself).

Answer (score 0):

It depends purely on your requirement.If an error occurs on asp.net page do you want to custom handle it like,
Do you want to redirect/display error page like please contact your administrator otherwise yellow screen of death page is displayed(default).
And if you want to a timeout,then you can have a pop up and redirect it to the home page.

Comment: The question is mostly from teh other direction here. the error is unhandle d(so noarmally the yellow screen of death). So from asp.net side it is clear, but my problem is how does java see this.